# Is it possible to merge two C# attributes into one?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm using EF6 code first in one of my company's projects. In the project there are a couple of properties in POCO classes that store Persian date information
(for example 1394/01/24). In our database these values are stored in "CHAR(10)" columns.

I use string properties to store these values in my POCOs and have to attach  "ColumnAttribute" and "StringLengthAttribute" to every date property:

```
public class MyPoco
{
    ...

    [Column(TypeName="CHAR")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength=10)]
    public string MyDate {get; set;}

    ...
}
```

I'm curious to know if I there is a way to create a custom attribute that combines behaviours of those two attributes so that I could do something like this:

```
public class MyPoco
{
    ...

    [DateColumn]
    public string MyDate {get; set;}

    ...
}
```

where "DateColumnAttribute" applies what those two attributes do. It can definitely reduce typing.

Comment: no thats not how it works...

Comment: an attribute is a class too ... that would mean that you need multiple inheritance to merge the two... and that's not supported by c#

Comment: But you should be able to create a new Custom Attribute that has the semantics of these two.

Answer (score 1):

As Florian stated: that's no how it works

An Attribute is in the end a class which derives from a base class Attribute. What you are trying to do, is to create a new attribute (class), which combines the properties of both attributes Column and StringLength.

This is not possible, because we would have to create a new attribute, which derives from both attributes together, but that's not possible, since .NET does not allow multiple inheritance.

Also it's a question of code style. If you could do what you want, you would hide the original intended behavior to the developer. He would have to open the new attribute and realize, it's a combination of two others. Everything that obfuscates the code is commonly regarded bad behavior (except it enhances readability of course)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my opinion obfuscation is not always a bad idea especially when it can prevent junior developers from messing everything up (for example by adding just one of the attributes instead of both by mistake) :)

Comment: That's not entirely wrong, but don't give all the blame to the juniors ;) but in that case I would recommend to create a Unit Test which would check that. We had similiar problems. Since we added some static checks to make sure, the attributes match the property types and other stuff, we solved most of these problems ;)