# Can I combine multiple [ServiceKnownType] attributes into one?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Say I have a generic abstract base class `Fred` and derived generic classes `Jim` and `Bob` and `Billy`...

```
public abstract class Fred<T> { }
public class Jim<T> : Fred<T> { }
public class Bob<T> : Fred<T> { }
public class Billy<T> : Fred<T> { }
```

If I want to have a WCF service method that returns one of the derived types, then in order to avoid a serialisation exception, I need to decorate the service method with four [ServiceKnownType] attributes...

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Fred<DooHickey>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Jim<DooHickey>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Bob<DooHickey>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Billy<DooHickey>))]
public Fred<DooHickey> GetDooHickey(int ID) {
  // Whatever...
}
```

Is it possible to create a new attribute that combines these four `[ServiceKnownType]` attributes into one, enabling me to do...

```
[OperationContract]
[NewServiceKnownType(typeof(NotSureWhatWouldGoHere))]
public Fred<DooHickey> GetDooHickey(int ID) {
  // Whatever...
}
```

Where the `[NewServiceKnownType]` attribute would know about the four classes, and would allow me to decorate the method with one line instead of four.

Anyone know if this is even possible?

**Edit:** I discovered that I can get part way with this by using a method to return the known types. See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for the details, which enables me to create a class called `KnownTypeHelper` containing the following method...

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTheTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider) {
  return new List<Type> {
    typeof(Fred<DooHickey>),
    typeof(Jim<DooHickey>),
    typeof(Bob<DooHickey>),
    typeof(Billy<DooHickey>),
  };
}
```

Then I can decorate my service method with just one line, using a variation of the `ServiceKnownType` attribute...

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType("GetTheTypes", typeof(KnownTypeHelper))]
public Fred<DooHickey> GetDooHickey(int ID) {
  // Whatever...
}
```

This works fine, but ties the `GetTheTypes()` method to the specific generic type. I tried making the `GetTheTypes()` method generic, and doing this...

```
[ServiceKnownType("GetTheTypes<DooHickey>", typeof(KnownTypeHelper))]
```

...but this threw an exception as it couldn't find a method of the right name. It evidently interpreted the `<DooHickey>` as part of the method name, not as a generic type.

So, is there a way to make a generic version of the method that returns the list of types?

Comment: It is not possible, see this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620891/is-it-possible-to-merge-two-c-sharp-attributes-into-one

Comment: @NibblyPig Please see my updated question. I found an overload of the attribute that gets me part way. Do you know if this could be made generic? Thanks

Comment: Technically you can't but you could put something into an attribute if you wanted to hack it. For example if you created your own `[GenericTypeSpecifyingAttribute(typeof(DooHickey)]`, I think you would be access to that in your method via the `ICustomAttributeProvider` parameter and build the type list using it. It is a bit of a hack though. In the end WCF needs to know exactly what a contract can be (derived classes) so it can serialise correctly. It defines its contracts up front in your WSDL so generics don't play nicely.

Comment: @NibblyPig Thanks, I did something similar to that, but was hoping there was a way of making tha attribute generic. Not sure why you can't do this, as WCF would know from the type on the attribute, but if you can't you can't! Thanks again